# How do I add Image/Vector Asset to a border of a circular textview

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, textview

**My Circular textView Drawable**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="#e5e5e5" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp" />
    <size
        android:width="15dp"
        android:height="15dp" />

</shape>
```

**My TextView**

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/circular_text_view"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="MP"
            android:textColor="#333333" />
```

[What I want my TextView to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZfio.png)

[This is what mine looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ln0Vd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created sample like that you can Customise according to your need

Here is my sample image for your reference
[image: you can customise my code accordingly to your image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/rewards_icon"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/_60sdp"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_card_giftcard_24"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/rewards_tv"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_minus20sdp"
                                android:background="@drawable/profile_reward_count"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="0"
                                android:textColor="@color/quiz_prev_text"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/rewards_icon"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />                            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the code for shape

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid
        android:color="@color/quiz_submit"/>

    <size
        android:width="25dp"
        android:height="25dp"/>
</shape>
```

I hope my answer will help you!!

Comment: It did give me a hint on how to approach it but in my case I want my image/vector asset in the middle of top and end of the view. Do you know if I could do it with just the constraints ?

Comment: yeah,layout_constraintTop_toTopOf and layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf of your textView and after that give margin in negative it will declare your desire output